# Are there any cross platform mobile application Advertising APIs

Tags: cross-platform, visual-studio

Are there any cross platform mobile application advertising APIs?

There are many that profess to be, but are often IOS, Android and Mobile Web. Since I am using Visual Studio Cordova Universal Apps development, I would be looking for Windows Mobile/Phone, Android and IOS. A single API is the only option that really makes sense to me.

In our country, the Android Merchant Account is disabled, so advertising API is the only real option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AdMob](http://admob.com) has a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin for Android and iOS (I'm not sure if it works on Windows Phone). It's unofficial but seems to work. See [GitHub](https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova)

Comment: You are a genius - See https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro